# Guice configuration error

Tags: java, configuration, dependency-injection, guice

I'm trying to use Google Guice with the @Inject and @Singleton properties as follows:

I have:

1. A Module with an empty `configure()` method.
2. An interface IFoo
3. A class Foo (implementing IFoo), annotated with @Singleton, with a parameter-less constructor annotated with @Inject. This is the single annotated constructor.

The classes, constructor and interface are public, and still I'm getting the following error:

> No implementation for IFoo was bound.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean you get the error when doing this?

```
IFoo foo = injector.getInstance(IFoo.class);
```

Well then it is obvious. If the `configure()` is empty how should guice know with what class to satisfy the dependency for `IFoo`.

Just add this in the `configure()` method and it should work. Now guice knows with what class to satisfy the dependency.

```
bind(IFoo.class).to(Foo.class);
```

---

If you don't want to configure this in the module you can annotate the interface. e.g.

```
@ImplementedBy(Foo.class)
public interface IFoo {
  ...
}
```

The `@Singleton` annotations only tells guice to return the same instance for the class (the Singleton Pattern) everytime a request for the class is made via `Injector.getInstance()` instead of creating a new instance everytime. But note that this is only a Singleton per Injector rather then per Classloader.

Comment: Doesn't the @Singleton annotation on Bar tell Guiced that it is the concrete implementation of IBar?

I don't like to have a large Module() - I prefer to annotate classes. How does one accomplish that with Guist?